# Python 3 loading large image file (or video stream)

Tags: python, file, image-processing, video-streaming

I am working with a custom multi-channel camera that saves the data in a particular format. The generated file starts with a header and then image data, the header determines how I should interpret the data.

For example, a file consist of 3 channels with a set height and width. Each channel has it's frame size and should be interpreted by a certain amount of bytes, usually per byte.

What I am currently doing is opening the file as 'rb', no buffering because the current files I am working with are 2-20MB. I use file.read(bytes from the header) and save that in a list, which I put in another list (because the file can be a video stream). The problem with this approach is, that a file that consist of only 6 frames with 3 channels already takes me 14 seconds to load. Eventually I will make a video player, where you can drag and drop a bar to go to a certain frame or just let it play. However I can already see problems with lag and long loading times.

So far I am using Qt4, OpenCV to convert my raw data to images, numpy and matplotlib.

Are there any better aproaches to my problem than simply reading per byte? I want to heavily reduce loading time. Perhaps there are some libraries out there that can help me, or some already existant code.

Comment: standard recommendation would be to read the data in some CPU/memory friendly block size and go from there; i.e. 4096 or 8192 bytes (e.g. 2**12)

Comment: `'rb'` says you want to open a file for reading in binary mode.  it doesn't say anything about buffering (which you almost certainly want)

Comment: I could load in a couple of frames, say 5. How many bytes that would be depends on the amount of channels, bytes, width and height fields in the header. Yes I am reading in raw binary data, I suppose setting the buffering option would help!

Comment: What about multi-threading? Have 5 different threads load a frame each.

Comment: you should be able to max out most IO devices with basic python code when you're operating with reasonable sized blocks, going with multiple threads will just cause issues later.  the blocks you read from the device don't need to match the size of the file format, just call `fd.read(4096)` and process the resulting bytes object

Comment: Great, I'll give that a try. I would still have to slice those 4096 bytes to single bytes (or more, dependant on the header). Thanks!